# Do mouseEvent and keyEvent use the same integer codes?

Tags: java, events, input

*mouseEvent* and *keyEvent* have methods `getButton()` and `getKeyCode()`
which *both* return an *integer* which match a constant of their repective button (like Mouse2). I am writing an input class and would like to know if **any** of their integers overlap with each other;

i.e.

`getKeyCode()` for "C" returns **3**

`getButton()` for "mouse3" also returns **3**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are distinct constant sets in distinct classes so, it is likely that the same values appear in both. You can see the values by yourself by decompiling those classes in your favorite IDE.

**Either way, you should NOT write code that relies on wether their values overlap or not**.

There is no contract in the javadoc for the actual value, and the point of having constants is that you should not worry about the underlying value. If you rely on the actual value you are doing something wrong.

Comment: so, if i wanted to have a class that could be accessed to ask for the current keys pressed, how should i do it? (currently i have an arrayList of integers of the key/mouse codes) which an integer is checked against in a method and return true/false;

Comment: Then instead of a list of 'Integer' use a list of 'InputEvent' (the parent class to both 'KeyEvent' and 'MouseEvent').

Answer (score 1):

Yes, some overlap.

As shown [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html), BUTTON1 from MouseEvent and KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD from KeyEvent are both 1.